# How to find and delete a set of words/numbers anywhere in a file?

Tags: notepad++

So, I've got a file with multiple sets of numbers separated by spaces. The numbers I'm dealing with range from 1 to ~5000, and are distributed into separate lines each containing a set of the total. The numbers in each line aren't (necessarily) in order and none of the numbers in the entire list repeat.

Now, what I need to do is create lines with new sets of numbers taken from the sets I've already got, and delete the old numbers so there's no repetition.

Let me give an example. Say I've got the following lines:

```
173 177 178 180 183 184 186 187 188 254 255 256 257
1385 1408 1420 1512 2241 2242 2335 2358 2361
3757 3758 3759 3761 3762 3791 3792 3793 3999 4001 4026
```

And I want to add the following line with numbers taken from the previous lines:

```
173 177 178 186 2241 2242 2335 3758 3759 3762 3999
```

My question is: how do I add that line in *and* delete the repeated numbers in the previous lines? I know I could always do it manually with the 'Find' function, but the sets I'm dealing with are much longer than these. It would take me all day to find all the duplicates individually and then go back and delete them one by one.

I know very little about commands and such in Notepad++, but is there one that could do that for me or at least facilitate the process?

Comment: Is there any line based information that you are trying to maintain?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question, but each line is unique and is composed of a unique set of numbers. If I want to create a new line with a new set of numbers, those numbers have to be removed from the other lines they appear in.

Comment: No. I figured all that from the initial question.I was wondering what information is in the way the lines are split. E.g. can we first put it all into one line?

Comment: Why `178` & `186` are putting in the new line but not `180`, `183` ... ? What are the rules to take some numbers and not other ones?

Comment: Using a file with one number per line will be much easier.

Comment: *ctrl-alt-delor*: It can't be put all in one line because each represents a separate 'entity,' so to speak. You could put all the numbers in a single line, sure, but they'd have to be put back afterwards.

Comment: *Toto*: There are external factors that determine what numbers get taken out and grouped in with other numbers. The important thing is that I know the set of numbers I want to add in; what I don't know is how to take out the duplicates from the other lines afterwards without going through the list one by one.

Comment: It's  really easy to remove duplicates, the problem is how do you select what numbers you keep?

Comment: May be I'm wrong but I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1686)

Comment: Notepad++ supports regular expression search and replace. I'm finding it hard to precisely define your problem to create a regex though. Maybe try to formulate the simplest possible example, read up on regex and, if you're still struggling, ask for some help?

Answer (score 1):

#### Assuming you already have the new line to compare with, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\A|\G[\s\S]*?)\b(\d+)\b\s(?=[\s\S]+\b\2\b)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               # group 1
    \A              # beginning of file
  |               # OR
    \G              # resrtart from last match position
    [\s\S]*?        # 0 or more any character, not greedy
)               # end group
\b              # word boundary
(\d+)           # group 2, 1 or more digit
\b              # word boundary
\s              # any kind of space
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    [\s\S]+         # 1 or more any character
    \b              # word boundary
    \2              # backreference to group 2, the number to find
    \b              # word boundary
)               # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. the acronym)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]